# Mass effect 3 gibbed save editor and DLC Arrival

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

I'm using gibbed editor to set DLC Arrival as succesfully completed. But it doesn't work. I set 7451 as true and still Anderson blames Shepard in blowing up the mass relay in Batarian's system. Why? Is there any more plot ids need to be set? And what plot ids add Conrad Verner into game? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You seem to have two fairly different questions in there. You may want to ask a separate question about Conrad.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm more interesting in how to solve the dlc arrival import problem then. I've looked everywhere, I didn't find the solution.

Comment: You can ask both questions, I'm just saying you can ask the other one in a new post and keep this one and have an answer for both, but in two different places.

Answer (score 3):

That seems to be working as intended.

The Arrival DLC ends up with Shepard blowing up the Alpha Relay and sacrificing a Batarian colony in the process. At the beginning of Mass Effect 3, Anderson uses that as explanation for Shepard's incarceration.

If Arrival *isn't* completed, then the Alliance's 103rd Marine Division is said to have carried out that mission and destroyed the Alpha Relay, but didn't make it out alive. In that instance, Anderson will blame Shepard for working with Cerberus to explain the incarceration.

Comment: thank you. but I'm still confused by GAW asset - because it doesn't depend on dlc complete flag, there is 'Alliance's 103rd Marine Division is said to have carried out that mission and destroyed the Alpha Relay, but didn't make it out alive' ANYWAY. Is this normal or it's a bug?